# Blob data replace '+' with space

Tags: iphone, mysql, character-encoding, blob

I have an iphone app that converts a image into NSData & then converts into base64 encoded string.

When this encoded string is submitted to server in server's database, while storing on server '+' gets converted into 'space' and so the decoder does not work properly.

I guess the issue is with default encoding of table in database. Currently its latin, i tried changing it to UTF8 but problem still exits.

Any other encoding, please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course - that has nothing to do with encoding. It is the format of the `POST` and `GET` parameters which creates a clash with base64. In http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table you see alternatives which are designed to make base64 work with URLs etc.

One of these variants is "Base64 with URL and Filename Safe Alphabet ([RFC 4648](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#RFC_4648) 'base64url' encoding)" which replaces the `+` with `-` and the `/` with `_`.

Another alternative would be to replace the offending characters `+/=` by their respective hexrepresentations with `%xx` - but that makes the data unnecessarily longer.

Comment: :So what must I do? I must change encoding logic or I must convert this encoded string into url encoded string so as to be sure that universal decoder like openssl can decode my submitted data?

Comment: You can do any of them, depending what you have on the receiving side. Replacing is quite straightforward, and urlencoding as well - do whatever suits you best.